# How do I avoid repeatedly starting cmd.exe in this batch file to run AWS CLI commands?

Tags: windows, batch-file, amazon-s3, cmd, aws-cli

By following various examples, I've managed to cobble together a working batch file that uses the AWS CLI to extract file listings from AWS S3 buckets and append a URL to the start of them.

I know you can do something similar in programs like 'S3 Browser', but I needed a "one-click solution". The result is below; when I run it, it successfully extracts listings from 4 sub-folders and saves them to 4 different text files.

It definitely does what I want, but I think it's a pretty clumsy effort. For example, I'm starting, and then closing, cmd.exe on every loop to send commands.

I tried putting it outside the loop; it *seems* like it should be easy to do but, as a raw beginner to batch files, I can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
@echo off 

REM ----------- SET VARIABLES -------------------
REM Set AWS Base URL
REM ----------------
set BaseURL=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

REM SET AWS Bucket Name
REM -------------------
set Bucket=XXXXXX

REM SET Bucket Sub-Folder
REM ---------------------
set sub-folder-1=XXXXXX

REM SET Bucket Sub-Folder
REM ---------------------
set sub-folder-2=XXXXXX

REM SET Bucket Sub-Folders
REM ----------------------
set sub-folder-3=MP4 MP3 PDF Thumbnails

REM Set AWS file download location
set DownloadAWSFileTo=C:\Desktop

REM ------------------------------------------------

REM Loop through all sub-folders
    For %%a in (%sub-folder-3%) do (
        REM Start AWS CLI, download/save directory list to desktop, and close CMD window
        start cmd.exe /k "aws s3 ls s3://%Bucket%/%sub-folder-1%/%sub-folder-2%/%%a/ > %DownloadAWSFileTo%\filelist.txt" ^& exit

    REM Pause for 3 seconds to make sure CMD is finished
        timeout /t 3

    REM Remove everything from AWS directory list EXCEPT file names
        for /f "tokens=4 delims= " %%i in (filelist.txt) DO ( echo %%i >> CLEANfilelist.txt)

    REM Append URL structure to beginning of each line and make new list
        for /F "delims=" %%j in (CLEANfilelist.txt) do echo.%BaseURL%/%Bucket%/%sub-folder-1%/%sub-folder-2%/%%a/%%j >> %%a-URLs-%sub-folder-2%-AWS.txt

    REM Delete unwanted text files
        del filelist.txt
        del CLEANfilelist.txt
   )
```

Comment: You realize that cmd.exe is what is running the batch file in the first place?  There's no obvious reason why you need to start a child instance in order to run your `aws` command.  (I have no idea what you mean by "putting it outside the loop".)

Comment: Ha... I feel pretty stupid now: I did know that-dunno what I was doing there. I amended the code, and it's working beautifully (with just 1 window) now. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include the solution as it invalidtes the question for future readers. Instead answer your own question. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Sorry; I "unedited" it again, and posted the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Just removing cmd.exe did the trick...

```
REM Loop through all sub-folders
For %%a in (%sub-folder-3%) do (
    REM AWS CLI command to get directory file list and save to desktop
        aws s3 ls s3://%Bucket%/%sub-folder-1%/%sub-folder-2%/%%a/ > %DownloadAWSFileTo%\filelist.txt

    REM Remove everything from AWS directory list EXCEPT file names
        for /f "tokens=4 delims= " %%i in (filelist.txt) do (echo %%i >> CLEANfilelist.txt)

    REM Append URL structure to beginning of each line and make new list
        for /F "delims=" %%j in (CLEANfilelist.txt) do echo.%BaseURL%/%Bucket%/%sub-folder-1%/%sub-folder-2%/%%a/%%j >> %%a-URLs-%sub-folder-2%-AWS.txt

    REM Delete unwanted text files
        del filelist.txt
        del CLEANfilelist.txt
)

REM Pause to finish final file cleanup
timeout /t 3
```